# Is there a way to get get the current document using cm.getDoc() and later use cm.swapDoc() to inset that document?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I have an editor that is using CodeMirror. I called `cm.getDoc()` and have stored the results of that. Now, I would like to replace a document with the one I had stored with `cm.getDoc()`. I tried to use `cm.swapDoc()` but it doesn't work. I was wondering if there was another way.